# Update command not firing datasource's update transport method - Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

Hi I am returning a data table from a stored procedure which is used to bind the grid. No Identity field is returned from that data table. in this scenario please help me out with firing 'update', 'destroy' and 'create'.

This is my controller method,

```
 public JsonResult Employee_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["manualconn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand("usp_FetchUserDetails", con);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }

   //     }

    }
```

This is the part of my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var Employee = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "userDetailsId",
    fields: {
        "userDetailsId": { type: "number" },
        "Name": { type: "string" },
        "Department": { type: "string" },
        "Role": { type: "string" },
        "Email": { type: "string" },


    }
});

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '@Url.Action("Employee_Read", "UserSummary")',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            //data: {
            //    test: $("#Names").val()
            //}
        },
        destroy: 
        //function (e) {
                  {
            url: '@Url.Action("Update_Details", "UserSummary")',
               type: "POST",
          //  dataType: "json",
            //data: {
            //    DAKy: $("#Names").val(),
            //    DIKy: $("#btntxt").val()
            //}
        },
        create: {
            url: '@Url.Action("Update_Details", "UserSummary")',
            type: "POST",
           // dataType: "json",
            //cache: false,
            //data: {
            //    AKy: $("#Names").val(),
            //    IKy: $("#btntxt").val()
            //}
        },
        update:         
        {
            url: '@Url.Action("Update_Details", "UserSummary")',
            type : "POST"
            //data: {
            //  AKy: $("#Names").val(),
            //  IKy: $("#btntxt").val()
            //       }
        }
              },
    error: function (e) {
        // handle error
        alert("Status: " + e.status + "\n" + e.errorThrown);
    },
    pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "userDetailsId",
                        model: Employee
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                editable: "inline",
                //toolbar: ["create", "save"],
                autobind: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                    //{
                    //    field: "userDetailsId",
                    //    title: "userDetailsId",
                    //    width: "50px",

                    //},
                    {
                                field: "Name",
                                title: "Name",
                                width: "75px",
                                template: "<input id='Name' type='text' value='#: Name #' readonly> </input>",
                                editable:false,
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Department",
                                title: "Department",
                                width: "50px",
                                editor: ddlFetchDepartments


                            },
                            {
                                field: "Role",
                                title: "Role",
                                width: "50px",
                                editor: ddlFetchRoles

                            },
                            {
                                field: "Email",
                                title: "Email",
                                width: "100px",
                                template: "<input type='text' id='Email' size='35' value='#:Email#' readonly> </input>",
                                editable:false,
                            },

                             {
                                 command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "75px"
                             },
                             { command: { text: "custom edit", click: showDetails },title: " ", width: "60px" }

                ],
            });



            function showDetails(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                //debugger;
                var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                alert("View Details\n Name : " + dataItem.Name+"\nuserDetailsId : "+dataItem.userDetailsId); 
                @{

           //   ((MockProject.Controllers.UserSummaryController)this.ViewContext.Controller).Update_Details();

               }

            }

            function ddlFetchDepartments(container, options) {

                $('<input name="Departments" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')

                    .appendTo(container)

                    .kendoDropDownList({

                        dataTextField: "deptName",

                        dataValueField: "deptId",

                        autoBind: false,

                        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

                            transport: {

                                read: {

                                    url: '@Url.Action("FetchDepartments", "UserSummary")',
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    dataType: "json"

                                },
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        id: "deptId",
                                        value: "deptName"
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        })

                    });
            }
                function ddlFetchRoles(container, options) {

                    $('<input name="Roles" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')

                        .appendTo(container)

                        .kendoDropDownList({

                            dataTextField: "roleName",

                            dataValueField: "roleId",

                            autoBind: false,

                            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

                                transport: {

                                    read: {

                                        url: '@Url.Action("FetchRoles", "UserSummary")',
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        dataType: "json"

                                    },

                                    schema: {

                                        model: {

                                            id: "roleId",
                                            value: "roleName"

                                        }

                                    }
                             }
                            })
                        });
                }
            @*@{
                ((HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).Method1();
            }*@
    </script>
<br/>


&nbsp; <button type="button" id="btn_addUser" > &nbsp;Add User</button> 
&nbsp;  &nbsp;
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden" name="btn_save" class="k-button k-button-icontext" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="saveDataToDb()" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function saveDataToDb() {

    }

    $('#btn_addUser').click(function () {

        document.getElementById('btn_save').style.visibility = "visible";
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').addRow();
    });

    function onEdit(e) {
        //Custom logic to default value
        var name = $("#AddSingleSuppliment").text();

        // If addition
        if (e.model.isNew()) {
            //set field
            e.model.set("Name", name); // Name: grid field to set
        }
    }

</script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_addUser").kendoButton({
            spriteCssClass: "k-icon iconplus"
        });

    });
</script>


<style scoped>
    .k-button .k-image {
        height: 16px;
    }

    .demo-section {
        width: 500px;
    }

    .iconplus {
        background-image: url("../content/icons/plus.png");
        background-size: contain;
        /*background-position: 0 -64px;
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-self: auto;*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Try defining in the schema the `id`... it is commented out and it is required when doing update, create, destroy

Comment: `id` should be the identifier in your database. The one that will allow the server to insert the record in the DB. This value should be returned by the server once successfully inserted.

Comment: "No Identity field is returned from that data table." Then how do you suppose to implement updates and deletes without the unique id that identifies it in the database?

Comment: Ok. Thanks Bret. Now I have set the Id as 'userDetailsId'. Still It is not firing the corresponding update delete events. Please see the same. I have updated the code